# Cannot read property '0' of undefined in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an usecase.
I have a simple hard coded array in one of the service of angular project.
One of the method in the service is returning back the hardcoded array.

No I am tryinh to access the element of the array using index in the component which is injecting that particular service.
But I am getting Cannot read property '0' of undefined
How can I define the array in component?

My service looks like
sample-service.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SampleServiceService {

  constructor() { }
  user : any = [
                  {
                    fullName : 'John'
                  },
                  {
                    fullName : 'Peter'
                  }
                ];


  public get currentUserDetails() {
    return this.user;
  }
}
```

My component class looks like:
sample.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleServiceService } from '../services/sample-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _sampleService : SampleServiceService) { }

  username : string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.username = this._sampleService.currentUserDetails.user[0].fullName;        
  }

}
```

Component HTML: sample.component.html

```
    <p>sample works!</p>

<h1>{{username}}</h1>
```

Browser Console looks like : 
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax to access it in `sample.component.ts` is:

```js
this.username = this._sampleService.currentUserDetails[0].fullName;
```

You don't have the "user" attribute before `fullName`.

If you want to keep the way you're calling it, you can modify your getter (`currentUserDetails`):

```js
get currentUserDetails() {
  return {user: this.user};
}
```

Comment: Can you modify the array in such a way that if I am not changing the component
i.e., this.username = this._sampleService.currentUserDetails.user[0].fullName;
Still will get the output of John

Comment: Yeah, if you turn it into an object that contains an attribute pointing to an array... but it's a really weird structure. I'll modify my answer adding something in the getter function in order to make it a little less weird.

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.username = this._sampleService.currentUserDetails[0].fullName;
      console.log(this.username);   
  }
```